# Images appear stretched out in flask created report

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I created a web app that allows users to upload a csv and returns a pdf with visualisations based on the data inputed (specifically for a csv files from a Google My Business export).

The problem is that the visualisations either appear stretched out in the pdf generated by my app or some of the labels are cut off. I have tried resizing the plots but this doesn't seem to have an impact on my result.

This is what the plots look like
Example 1:
[image: First Image]

Example 2:
[image: Second Image]

Here is the code I have used to create these visualisations:

```
def transform():
    disc = open('clean.csv')
    disc2 = open('clean_two.csv','w')
    #cleaning up csv
    for row in disc:
        row = row.strip()
        row = row[1:-1]
        row = row.replace('""','"')
        disc2.write(row+'\n')
    disc2.close()
    disc.close()
    discovery = pd.read_csv('clean_two.csv')
    discovery_clean = discovery.iloc[1:]
    cols = list(discovery_clean.columns[4:])
    discovery_clean[cols] = discovery_clean[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
    #return discovery_clean
    #first figure
    with PdfPages('plots.pdf') as pdf:
        plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
        ax = discovery_clean[cols].sum().plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
        ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.set_title('Overview\n',fontsize='15',color='black')
        ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=15)
        for x in ax.patches:
            ax.text(x.get_x()-.09,x.get_height()+20,\
            f'{int(x.get_height()):,}',fontsize=15,color='black')
        plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20,10)
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()      
        #second image
        mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
        disc_plot = discovery_clean.groupby('Business name')['Total views'].sum().nlargest(10)
        labels = list(disc_plot.index)
        nums = (disc_plot.values).astype(int)
        def actual_nums(vals):
            a = np.round(vals/100.*nums.sum())
            return a
        explode=(0.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
        plt.pie(nums,labels=labels,autopct=actual_nums,explode=explode,radius=1)
        plt.title("Total Views per Location\n",fontsize=20)
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()
        #setting metadata
        pdf_plots = pdf.infodict()
        pdf_plots['Title'] = 'Reports'
    return pdf_plots
```

Comment: Those are two different problems. For example 1, you might want to use `tight_layout()` to make everything fit into the figure. For example 2, you probably forgot to set the aspect of the axes, `ax.set_aspect("equal")`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pdf.savefig(bbox_inches='tight') works for the first example, but still having troubles with the pie plot...even after trying your suggestions